# Advanced Custom Fields/PHP issue

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I apologize if this is answered elsewhere, but I'm having an issue with this ACF code here: http://goo.gl/9onrFN I want the client to be able to add a portfolio site link (if applicable) to the artist page and the link would say "View Artist's Website" and the link would take the user to the artist's site in a new window. How would I go about not making this text not visible, unless there was a url entered into the custom field on the post? Here's the code:

```
<p><?php the_field('contact_phone_number'); ?><br />
                    or <a href="mailto:<?php the_field('contact_email'); ?>"><?php the_field('contact_email'); ?></a><br />
                    View <a href="<?php the_field('artist_website'); ?>" target="_blank">Artist's Website</a></p>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if a ACF field is set with:

```
if(get_field('artist_website')) {
    the_field('artist_website');
}
```

Using the_field will simple echo the contents of your field, whereas get_field will return the value which is a lot more helpful. For example you could write the above code as:

Note: get_field simple returns the value of the field, if you want to check if a valid url has been entered you will have to use a regular expression.

Below is your code with an if statement performing an empty field check:

```
<p>
<?php the_field('contact_phone_number'); ?><br />
or <a href="mailto:<?php the_field('contact_email'); ?>"><?php the_field('contact_email'); ?></a>
<?php if(get_field('artist_website')) { ?>
    <br />View <a href="<?php the_field('artist_website'); ?>" target="_blank">Artist's Website</a>
```

You may find your code easier to read by pre-setting your variables and including HTML in the echo:

```
<p>
<?php
$contact_phone_number = get_field('contact_phone_number');
$contact_email = get_field('contact_email');
$artist_website = get_field('artist_website');

echo "{$contact_phone_number}<br />";
echo "or <a href='mailto:{$contact_email}'>{$contact_email}</a><br/ >;
if($artist_website) {
     echo "View <a href='{$artist_website}' target='_blank'>Artist's website</a>";
}
?>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you elaborate more on your second example? What exactly I need to add and where?

Comment: Figured it out:<?php if(get_field('artist_website')) { ?> View<a href="<?php the_field('artist_website'); ?>" target="_blank"> Artist's Website</a><?php } ?>

Comment: @user2263554 Glad its working for you. Can you tick my answer as the answer please - the code you used is the same as I gave.